# Google corechart map not showing anymore

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I have a map that is drawn by coordinates.
It was working 3 days ago but now it's not showing.

code:
    
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});

error:

> jsapi:22 A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script,
>   https://www.google.com/uds/?file=visualization&v=1&packages=corechart,
>   is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if
>   the device has poor network connectivity.google.loader.f @ jsapi:22
>   2jsapi:22 A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script,
>   https://www.google.com/uds/api/visualization/1.0/1195ca6324d5ce101c2f520f3c62c843/format+pt_PT,default+pt_PT,ui+pt_PT,corechart+pt_PT.I.js,
>   is invoked via document.write. This may be blocked by the browser if
>   the device has poor network connectivity.

I tryed to change to:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'map']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(CarregaMapa("map-geral","eda",continente,7,-1,"#FFF",1000,600));
```

and i get the error:

> loader.js:152 Uncaught TypeError: a.shift(...) is not a function(…)

**Update:**

I change to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'map']});

 MapaConcelhos.map = new          google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById(mapa), {
                scrollwheel: false,
                draggable: isDraggable,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                center: local,
                mapTypeId: "",
                backgroundColor: bk,
                zoom: zoomlocal
            });
```

but I have to add a polygon to the map:

```
var concelho = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: coords,
                idc: idconcelho,
                strokeColor: "black",
                strokeOpacity: 0.3,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: item.Cor ? item.Cor : "white",
                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                html: contentString 
            });

concelho.setMap(MapaConcelhos.map);
```

so the error is:

> setMap: not an instance of Map

Is it possible to add polygon to a visualization map?

Why can't I use the old code? Why jsapi is having warnings and the map and polygons are not drawn anymore?

**Old code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]})
var MapaConcelhos = CarregaMapa("map-geral","eda",continente,7,-1,"#FFF",1000,600);


var mapbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var centromapa = new google.maps.LatLng();
var isDraggable = !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
var longpress = false;


function CarregaMapa(mapa,mapatipo,local,zoomlocal,idd, bk,w,h) {

    var MapaConcelhos = {
        concelhos: [],
        addlegenda: function(item) {


        var leg = {
        ordem: item.Legenda_key,
        cor: item.Cor,
        label: item.Label
        }

        Array.prototype.inArray = function(comparer) { 
            for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++) { 
                if(comparer(this[i])) return true; 
            }
            return false; 
        }; 

        Array.prototype.sortOn = function(key){
            this.sort(function(a, b){
                if(a[key] < b[key]){
                    return -1;
                }else if(a[key] > b[key]){
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
        }

        Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(element, comparer) { 
            if (!this.inArray(comparer)) {
               Mapalegenda.push(element);
               Mapalegenda.sortOn("ordem")
               var legenda="<p><b>Legenda:</b></p>";
               for (var i=0; i<Mapalegenda.length; i++) {
               legenda = legenda +'<div id="map-legenda-linha"><div id="map-legenda-cor" style="background: ' + Mapalegenda[i].cor + ';"></div>' + Mapalegenda[i].label + '</div>';
               }
               document.getElementById("map-legenda").innerHTML = legenda;
            }
        }; 

      Mapalegenda.pushIfNotExist(leg, function(e) { 
            return e.cor === leg.cor && e.label === leg.label; 
        });


        },
        addConcelho: function(item) {
            //Set concelho coordenadas
            var coords = [];
            var coord = item.Coordenadas.split("|");
            for (var i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
                var latlng = coord[i].split(",");
                coords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[1], latlng[0]));
            }
            var contentString="<b>"+item.Nome+"</b>"+item.Descricao;
            //Create polygon
            var idconcelho=item.Id;
            var concelho = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: coords,
                idc: idconcelho,
                strokeColor: "black",
                strokeOpacity: 0.3,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: item.Cor ? item.Cor : "white",
                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                html: contentString 
            });

            MapaConcelhos.concelhos.push(concelho);
            concelho.setMap(MapaConcelhos.map);

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i=0; i< coords.length; i++) {
                bounds.extend(coords[i]);
                mapbounds.extend(coords[i]);
            }

            var centroconcelho = bounds.getCenter();
            var timer = null;



            if (isDraggable)
            {
             google.maps.event.addListener(concelho,"click",function(){
                showConcelho(concelho.idc);});
            }
            else
            {

            google.maps.event.addListener(concelho, 'mousedown', function(event){

             start = new Date().getTime();  
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(concelho, 'mouseup', function(){

                        end = new Date().getTime();
                            longpress = (end - start < 300) ? false : true;         
                        if (longpress)  showConcelho(concelho.idc);  
                    });

            }//else

           MapaConcelhos.addlegenda(item);
            if (item.Ultimo=="1")
            { 
                MapaConcelhos.map.fitBounds(mapbounds);
        MapaConcelhos.map.setCenter(local);
            }

           function isInfoWindowOpen(infoWindow){
                var map = infoWindow.getMap();
                return (map !== null && typeof map !== "undefined");
            }


                var minZoom=8;
                if (idd==41 || idd==-1) minZoom=7;

                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(MapaConcelhos.map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                        if (this.getZoom() < minZoom) {
                        this.setZoom(minZoom);
                         MapaConcelhos.map.setCenter(local);
                        }
                    });                         

            function showArrays(event) {
                var vertices = this.getPath();
                var contentString =this.html;
                infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
                infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                infoWindow.open(MapaConcelhos.map);                 
            }   

        function showConcelho(idc) {
                $.fancybox({
                        href : "/ficha.php?id="+idc,
                        width : w,
                        height   : h,
                        fitToView   : true,
                        autoSize    : false,
                        type: "iframe",
                        padding: 0,
                        openEffect : "elastic",
                        openSpeed  : 150,
                        aspectRatio : true,
                        closeEffect : "elastic",
                        closeSpeed  : 150,
                        closeClick : true,
                        scrolling : "auto",
                        preload   : true
                    });             
            }  

        },

        map: undefined,
        mapContainer: document.getElementById(mapa),
        initialize: function() {
            google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
             MapaConcelhos.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapa), {
                scrollwheel: false,
                draggable: isDraggable,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                center: local,
                mapTypeId: "",
                backgroundColor: bk,
                zoom: zoomlocal
            });


        }
    };

    var requester = {};            
    requester.Request = function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/scripts/concelhos.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: { tipo: mapatipo, distrito:idd},
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",
            dataType: "json",
        }).done(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                $.each(result, function(index, item) {
                    MapaConcelhos.addConcelho(item);
                });

            } else {


            }
        }).error(function() {
        });
    };



    MapaConcelhos.initialize();
    requester.Request();

 return MapaConcelhos;           

} //CarregaMapa
```

**New code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

google.charts.load('current', {
  'callback': function () {
var MapaConcelhos = CarregaMapa("map-geral","eda",continente,7,-1,"#FFF",1000,600);
  },
  'packages': ['corechart', 'map']
});

var mapbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var centromapa = new google.maps.LatLng();
var isDraggable = !('ontouchstart' in document.documentElement);
var longpress = false;


function CarregaMapa(mapa,mapatipo,local,zoomlocal,idd, bk,w,h) {

    var MapaConcelhos = {
        concelhos: [],
        addlegenda: function(item) {


        var leg = {
        ordem: item.Legenda_key,
        cor: item.Cor,
        label: item.Label
        }

        Array.prototype.inArray = function(comparer) { 
            for(var i=0; i < this.length; i++) { 
                if(comparer(this[i])) return true; 
            }
            return false; 
        }; 

        Array.prototype.sortOn = function(key){
            this.sort(function(a, b){
                if(a[key] < b[key]){
                    return -1;
                }else if(a[key] > b[key]){
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            });
        }

        Array.prototype.pushIfNotExist = function(element, comparer) { 
            if (!this.inArray(comparer)) {
               Mapalegenda.push(element);
               Mapalegenda.sortOn("ordem")
               var legenda="<p><b>Legenda:</b></p>";
               for (var i=0; i<Mapalegenda.length; i++) {
               legenda = legenda +'<div id="map-legenda-linha"><div id="map-legenda-cor" style="background: ' + Mapalegenda[i].cor + ';"></div>' + Mapalegenda[i].label + '</div>';
               }
               document.getElementById("map-legenda").innerHTML = legenda;
            }
        }; 

      Mapalegenda.pushIfNotExist(leg, function(e) { 
            return e.cor === leg.cor && e.label === leg.label; 
        });


        },
        addConcelho: function(item) {
            //Set concelho coordenadas
            var coords = [];
            var coord = item.Coordenadas.split("|");
            for (var i = 0; i < coord.length; i++) {
                var latlng = coord[i].split(",");
                coords.push(new google.maps.LatLng(latlng[1], latlng[0]));
            }
            var contentString="<b>"+item.Nome+"</b>"+item.Descricao;
            //Create polygon
            var idconcelho=item.Id;
            var concelho = new google.maps.Polygon({
                paths: coords,
                idc: idconcelho,
                strokeColor: "black",
                strokeOpacity: 0.3,
                strokeWeight: 1,
                fillColor: item.Cor ? item.Cor : "white",
                fillOpacity: 0.8,
                html: contentString 
            });

            MapaConcelhos.concelhos.push(concelho);
            concelho.setMap(MapaConcelhos.map);

            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            for (var i=0; i< coords.length; i++) {
                bounds.extend(coords[i]);
                mapbounds.extend(coords[i]);
            }

            var centroconcelho = bounds.getCenter();
            var timer = null;



            if (isDraggable)
            {
             google.maps.event.addListener(concelho,"click",function(){
                showConcelho(concelho.idc);});
            }
            else
            {

            google.maps.event.addListener(concelho, 'mousedown', function(event){

             start = new Date().getTime();  
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(concelho, 'mouseup', function(){

                        end = new Date().getTime();
                            longpress = (end - start < 300) ? false : true;         
                        if (longpress)  showConcelho(concelho.idc);  
                    });

            }//else

           MapaConcelhos.addlegenda(item);
            if (item.Ultimo=="1")
            { 
            //MapaConcelhos.map.fitBounds(mapbounds);
            //MapaConcelhos.map.setCenter(local);
            }

           function isInfoWindowOpen(infoWindow){
                var map = infoWindow.getMap();
                return (map !== null && typeof map !== "undefined");
            }


                var minZoom=8;
                if (idd==41 || idd==-1) minZoom=7;

                google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(MapaConcelhos.map, 'bounds_changed', function(event) {
                        if (this.getZoom() < minZoom) {
                        this.setZoom(minZoom);
                         MapaConcelhos.map.setCenter(local);
                        }
                    });                         

            function showArrays(event) {
                var vertices = this.getPath();
                var contentString =this.html;
                infoWindow.setContent(contentString);
                infoWindow.setPosition(event.latLng);
                infoWindow.open(MapaConcelhos.map);                 
            }   

        function showConcelho(idc) {
                $.fancybox({
                        href : "/ficha.php?id="+idc,
                        width : w,
                        height   : h,
                        fitToView   : true,
                        autoSize    : false,
                        type: "iframe",
                        padding: 0,
                        openEffect : "elastic",
                        openSpeed  : 150,
                        aspectRatio : true,
                        closeEffect : "elastic",
                        closeSpeed  : 150,
                        closeClick : true,
                        scrolling : "auto",
                        preload   : true
                    });             
            }  

        },

        map: undefined,
        mapContainer: document.getElementById(mapa),
        initialize: function() {
            google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
             MapaConcelhos.map = new google.visualization.Map(document.getElementById(mapa), {
                scrollwheel: false,
                draggable: isDraggable,
                disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                disableDefaultUI: true,
                center: local,
                mapTypeId: "",
                backgroundColor: bk,
                zoom: zoomlocal
            });


        }
    };

    var requester = {};            
    requester.Request = function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "/scripts/concelhos.php",
            type: "GET",
            data: { tipo: mapatipo, distrito:idd},
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=ISO-8859-1",
            dataType: "json",
        }).done(function(result) {
            if (result) {
                $.each(result, function(index, item) {
                    MapaConcelhos.addConcelho(item);
                });

            } else {


            }
        }).error(function() {
        });
    };



    MapaConcelhos.initialize();
    requester.Request();

 return MapaConcelhos;           

} //CarregaMapa
```

Answer (score 0):

definitely need to use the following library, remove `jsapi`

`<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

the `load` statement looks fine

`google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart', 'map']});`

however, `setOnLoadCallback` expects a reference to a function, not the result of a function

regardless, the `'callback'` can be added to the `load` statement as well

recommend using the following load statement...

```
google.charts.load('current', {
  'callback': function () {
    CarregaMapa("map-geral","eda",continente,7,-1,"#FFF",1000,600);
  },
  'packages': ['corechart', 'map']
});
```

Comment: Thanks. it's calling the function. theres's no error but it's not showing the map... code: MapaConcelhos.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(mapa), {
                  scrollwheel: false,
                  draggable: isDraggable,
                  disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
                  disableDefaultUI: true,
                  center: local,
                    mapTypeId: "",
                    backgroundColor: bk,
                    zoom: zoomlocal
                });

Comment: i'm thinking the options should be passed to the `draw` function, not the constructor --> `new google.maps.Map` -- if you could add the rest of the code and sample of the data to the question, it would help...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

To keep the old code working I had to use a frozen version...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?**v=3.25**&key=XXX>
```

I wonder if this version is retired what will hapen?

it's showing the same jsapi warnings but the map and polygons are drawn...

so the problem was with the version of the maps api...